# How to achive 10tps throughput for individual request in a thread group

Tags: jmeter

I have a jmeter script like below:

```
Thread group
+ Register client HTTP REQUEST
+ Health check HTTP REQUEST
+ Create event HTTP REQUEST
   + Constant timer 3000 ms
```

I have question below:

1. I have target throughput ie 10tps for each request ie register, healthcheck and event individually need to achieve throughput 10tps. Is there anyway i can set in jmeter to make sure server can handle it?
2. Does adding constant timer at create event will affect the average response time result?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration results in:

1. JMeter will execute `Register client HTTP REQUEST` as fast as it can
2. JMeter will execute `Health check HTTP REQUEST` as fast as it can
3. JMeter will wait for 3 seconds
4. JMeter will execute `Create event HTTP REQUEST` as fast as it can

According to [JMeter Glossary](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html):

> **Throughput** is calculated as requests/unit of time. The time is calculated from the start of the first sample to the end of the last sample. This includes any intervals between samples, as it is supposed to represent the load on the server.
>
> The formula is: `Throughput = (number of requests) / (total time).`

So the real throughput depends on 2 factors:

1. The number of threads (virtual users) in the Thread Group
2. Your application response time

If you're looking to a way of conducting load of exactly 10 requests per second - consider using [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-throughput-shaping-timer-plugin/) or [Precise Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Precise_Throughput_Timer)

With regards to the Constant Timer - its duration isn't included into request elapsed time, it will not have any impact on the average response time result but the throughput will be lower if the timer is there

Comment: hi @Dmitri T, i have a question. When i configure 50 thread is it meant every thread will use back the same connection to send the request ? In this case, server will always see 50 connection at its most?

Comment: Each virtual user opens a TCP connection to the server. However it might open up to 6 extra connections in order to download [embedded resources](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/web-testing-jmeter-how-properly-handle-embedded-resources-html-responses/). You can use [Server Hits Per Second](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HitsPerSecond/) listener to monitor the perceived load, it counts calls to the embedded resources.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Will check it out.